# Inserting records in a primary;foreign key columns from another table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-design

> EDIT: It's seemingly the term 'bridging tables' got what I need

I'm trying to insert a record in a table `produ_tag` with a primary and foreign key as columns.

**produ_tag**

[image: link to the table structure]

**products**

[image: products structure]

**tags**

[image: tags structure]

The first column `refHe` is the code of the product from `products` table, the second contains the tag for the product from `tags` table. The modeling software made this additional table so it can saves which product contains which tag which is necessary.

The problem is they're primary, so if I have a product with 2 tags, the record won't be inserted, as it has already the same product inserted previously.

Should I delete the primary thing for both? Or there is another way to handle this, as the modeling software rendered it that way.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a bridging table, but can you please share your structure of the `products` table and the `tags` table?

Comment: I added both to the subject

Comment: Different modeling tools treat PK in a bridging table differently.  One way is composite keys.  If I'm reading your description right, the PK for produ_tsag is (refHe, namCh) which is a composite key.  That should work, and should allow you to insert a product with 2 tags, or 2 products with the same tag.

Answer (score 1):

The `produ_tag` table is a "bridging table", and the the composite primary key will allow any number of tags (`namCh`) to be associated with a product (`refHe`), provided that the tag exists in the `tags` table and that the `(refHe, nameCh)` pair is unique (i.e. you can't associate the same product and tag more than once).

If you get an error trying to insert a tag, it's not due to a faulty PK setup. You're either trying to reference a tag that doesn't exist, or you're inserting a combination of values that are already present in the table.

Don't delete your primary keys. The only obvious problem I see is that there's no FK constraint from `produ_tag.refHe` to `products.refHe`.

Comment: See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table for optimal schema for many-to-many mapping table.